# Safe method parsing text files with a user provided script

Tags: python, node.js, etl

I'm looking for a way to parse text from a url that has been provided by a user, with a parser script that has also been provided by the user. eval is easy enough, but obviously super scary.  the end goal is to just allow a user to point my server a data source and tell my server how to read the data.

what is the best safest way to do this? python or node preferred, but i'm not limited to any specific language.

so for example.  this is a cvs document, but sometimes i'll have just a text file.
url: http://www.ams.usda.gov/mnreports/lm_xb803.txt

this python script can read the file from the url, and is stored on the database:

```
expected_length = 6
requiredFeilds = ['low','high']
requiredNonZero = ['low','high']

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
reader = csv.reader(response)
grade = None
date = None
first_row = True
keep_list = []

for row in reader:
    if len(row) != expected_length:
        continue

    if first_row:
        date_text = row[2]
    date_object = datetime.strptime(date_text, '%m/%d/%Y')
    date = date_object.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    first_row = False


row_label = row[0].strip()

row_label = re.sub('\s\s+',' ',row_label)
grade_labels = {
    'Select Cuts':'sl',
    'Choice Cuts':'ch',
    'Choice and Select Cuts':'slch',
    'Ground Beef':'grnd',
    'Beef Trimmings':'trim'
}
if row_label in grade_labels.keys():
    grade = grade_labels[row_label]
    continue

row.insert(0,grade)
row.append(date)

# ignore until grade is selected
if row[0] is None:
    continue

# check rqs
try:
    for field in requiredFeilds:
        if len(row[ormMap[field]]) == 0:
            raise Exception('required field missing')
except:
    continue

try:
    for field in requiredNonZero:
        if row[ormMap[field]] < 1:
            raise Exception('required field missing')
except:
    continue

keep_list.append(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any powerful-enough language that can be "safely sandboxed" to ensure a skilled, malevolent user can't do damage with the script (program) he or she supplies to be run -- not without OS support, that is.

Fortunately, OS support **is** feasible -- and at that point it becomes little relevant what language the script/program is written in.

If you spin up a virtual machine, and run the user-supplied program inside it with bounded resource and close supervision, you can make things pretty secure that way.

If you're willing to trade off some assurance of safety for less overhead, you could run the user program in a **BSD jail** -- BSD jails have been around for a long time and are very well matured and proven by experience to be dependable.

Linux containers offer a very similar approach, and promise, but just haven't been around anywhere that long, so, some might consider them riskier.

Further along the spectrum is Chrome's **Portable Native Client**, https://developer.chrome.com/native-client , which runs the user's program (appropriately compiled to machine code) in a presumably secure sandbox within a (Chrome) browser.

I'm sure there exist other solutions yet, with similar overall approaches, somewhere along the VM -> jails/containers -> NaCl spectrum or just barely outside of it.  Depending on how much overhead you can afford, I'd hew as close as possible to the "left" (VM) end of this spectrum -- rather than rely on any "supposedly sandboxed" runtime for a specific language... but maybe I'm just a pessimist about this!-)